# Inconsistent results on digital inputs (circuit review)

Tags: mosfet, raspberry-pi, esp32, kirchhoffs-laws, review

I am attempting to make a prototype automated testing jig for a ESP32S3 board with a Raspberry PI 3B+.
I am getting inconsistent results when reading the digital outputs state of the ESP32S3 on the RPI.
If I switch on a digital output, on the ESP32S3 and read the output on the RPI the input is not pulled low enough to register as a logic zero.

I have tried two boards and both have one pin that is not registering a logic zero (not the same pin) but the LED is on.

**The following is a equivalent diagramed of the circuit:**

SW1 is a stand in for the ESP32S3 output.

R3 is a stand in for the pull-up on the RPI GPIO.
[image: equivalent circuit diagramed]

Measurements done at the input pin on the actual board.

- SW1 close: It reads ~1V8.
- SW1 open: It reads 3V3 on the dot.
- The other pins that work are well below 0V8.

My current theory is that the 5V is shunting through the pull-up resistor on the RPI due to some variants in the silicon of M1 or the internal pullup of the RPI. This is based on 5V-3V3 = 1V7 (Loos hand Kirchhoff) witch loosely matches the 1V8 that is being read.

Am I correct with this theory? Can I switch from 5V to 3V3 to correct this or must I isolate the inputs, if my theory is correct.

[BSS138 information](https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/Shikues-BSS138/C112239). I am using this because of the stock level. [No stock](https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/Onsemi-BSS138/C52895) of the Onsemi branded one at this time.

**Miscellaneous Information:**

- I am assuming there is no difference in the current through the LED.
  There is no visible difference in the LED brightness. It will be a
  pain to get the actual amp reading.
- The RPI GPIO works fine if I short from the ground to the RPI GPIO PIN.
- It is 14 outputs and all inputs are configured with internal pull-up resistors on the RPI.
- Set the pin drive strength on the ESP32S3 to the maximum. No change.
- The jig is on a perf board.

Comment: Sounds as if the PI GPIO pins are configured as outputs. Can they drive an LED connected to GND (without your LED D1)? It is not a very good idea to feed a PI input pin via LED from +5 V, especially if the PI is turned off.

Comment: @Jens I can confirm that all the pins are set as input with a pullup. The 5V source is from the PI header so if the PI is off everything else is off.
Not sure I can drive the LEDs on the 3V3 source. The LED are blue with about a 2V7-3V0 forward voltage. Regardless valid point about sinking 5V via the GPIO is not a good idea.
I was planning on switching the power rail regardless when I time again. See if it is a fix.

Comment: Which pins behave that way? There may be system drivers installed, that reconfigure your I/O which you are not aware of. Audio, RTC, custom power switching, serial ports etc.

Comment: @Jens With ESP board A GPIO10 and GPIO23 fail the detection. This is the same IO pin on the ESP32. I moved the wire on the RPI to a different GPIO.
With ESP board B it fails on GPIO4 on the RPI. This is a different IO pin of the ESP32.
Hence my question about current shunting via the pull-up.

Comment: @jens to answer your other question. Everything in raspberry config is disabled and set to GPIO excluding the Serial Pins. The Serial is used to flash the ESP32.

Comment: I had a look at the JLC product description side(s) of BSS138. Did you accidentially use a wrong pin assignment of the MOSFET? If I ignore the mentioned pinout and just overlay the schematic symbol and the SOT23 case, then drain would be connected as gate, source as drain and gate as source. In such a configuration your circuit would still work, but from the FET just the internal body diode with a voltage drop of 0.8 V would be conducting. This can explain the 1.8 V with a low ESP output driving the LED without a working MOSFET, but the signal logic would be inverted.

Comment: I do not think, that an RPI pullup resistor can win against a properly driven BSS138, even an active high RPI output would have poor chances.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146781/discussion-between-jens-and-binder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switch the 5V supply out for the 3V3 one and it started working as expected. I am content with this.

After some extensive simulating.

I have found that I am expositing the inputs on the Raspberry PI 3B+ to the full 5V line. This is not ideal. My mistake in my first simulation was not noticing that I was using a photo diode and not a LED.

Simulating the on resistance of the MOSFET it is found to be that about 400 ohm would cause what I am seeing. I have put an ammeter inline to double check the current being used and found it to be not the case. Measurement do not add up.

I am assuming it is leakage via the pull-up and calling it a day.